# Retrieving Boolean value as text

Tags: c#, sql, gridview

In my application i have one value which is stored as boolean. 
How can i change that Boolean value to text when displaying in grid view.

I have this sql

```
SELECT     Driver.FirstName + Driver.LastName AS DriverName, Driver.PhoneNumber, 
           Booking.BookingId, Booking.DriverRating, Driver.CarId AS CarUsed 
FROM       Booking 
INNER JOIN Driver ON Booking.DriverId = Driver.DriverId 
WHERE      Booking.DriverRating = 0
```

I am retrieving all the all the driver rating which is false(0). Now when i display it to grid view i want to change boolean value false to unsatisfactory.

How can i do it within sql query?

Comment: How are you binding? Isn't there a object between the query and the gridview?

Comment: DriverRating ? "satisfactory" : unsatisfactory"

Comment: I grid view is getting information from sql data source which has the query above.

Comment: Everyone seems to be working on some rental/booking database today.. :)
If else can help you. e.g. IF(Booking.DriverRating=true,"x","y")

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How bout retrieving it from the server as a string to begin with?

For example

```
SELECT Driver.FirstName + Driver.LastName AS DriverName, Driver.PhoneNumber, Booking.BookingId,
 Case Booking.DriverRating When 0 then 'Unsatisfactory' else 'Satisfactory' end as DriverRating,   
Driver.CarId AS CarUsed 
FROM Booking 
INNER JOIN Driver ON Booking.DriverId = Driver.DriverId 
WHERE (Booking.DriverRating = 0)
```

Or in your case since you are already using a where clause:

```
SELECT Driver.FirstName + Driver.LastName AS DriverName, Driver.PhoneNumber, Booking.BookingId, 
    'Unsatisfactory' as DriverRating,
    Driver.CarId AS CarUsed 
FROM Booking INNER JOIN Driver ON Booking.DriverId = Driver.DriverId 
WHERE (Booking.DriverRating = 0)
```

Answer (score 1):

Booking.DriverRating -> case Booking.DriverRating when 0 then 'Unsatisfactory' else 'Satisfactory' end as 'Booking.DriverRating'